# JQuery typescript definition for .prop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following code:

```
// Populate the title of the selects on change and trigger a change
$('#modal .update-title')
    .change(function () {
        var $select = $(this),
        match = null,
        matchRow = null,
        title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title');
```

In typescript this sets the value of title to a bool. Then when I try and use it as follows I am getting an error:

```
$("#modal_Title_" + matchRow).val(title);
```

Is this another problem with the JQuery definition or something that I am doing wrong? When a check the definition file I see the following:

```
prop(propertyName: string): bool;
```

This does not seem to match the JQuery doc.

Comment: try `.val(title.toString());`, as that is values should be, strings.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery documentation is incorrect, and so is your type definition file.

Most properties are strings, but some are numbers (e.g. `.selectedIndex`) and some are booleans (`.checked` etc), and `$.fn.prop()` **does not** convert them all to strings.

The correct definition should be:

```
prop(propertyName: string): any;
```

There's already a [work item](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/358) listed on the TypeScript site to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

As @Alnitak pointed out, the return value should be 'any'.

I have fixed the jQuery definitions file at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) which is a fork from TypeScript's file, but with numerous fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery docs state that prop returns:

- a string when called with one argument
- a jQuery object when called with two arguments

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

So according to this the jquery.d.ts may be incorrect.

My recommendation would be to edit the jquery.d.ts to be correct in your project and raise a bug at typescript.codeplex.com

```
prop(propertyName: string): string;
```